# Is there a simple way to alphabetically order incoming string value separated by a comma using Ampscript in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

```
%%[
    <br><br>
    VAR @segmentProduct, @queryparams
    SET @segmentProduct = AttributeValue("SEGMENT_ENTITLEMENTS")
    SET @queryparams = BuildRowSETFromString(@segmentProduct,',')
    SET @rowCount = Rowcount(@queryparams)

    FOR @i = 1 to Rowcount(@queryparams) do
       SET @row = Row(@queryparams, @i)
       SET @name = Field(@row,1)
       IF @i == 1 THEN
        SET @comb1 = @name
       ELSEIF @i == 2 THEN
        SET @comb2 = @name
       ELSEIF @i == 3 then
        SET @comb3 = @name
       ELSE
       ENDIF
        NEXT @i
    <br><br>
    ]%%
    Original String: %%=v(@segmentProduct)=%%
    <br>
    <br>
    %%=v(@comb1)=%%
    <br>
    <br>
    %%=v(@comb2)=%%
    <br>
    <br>
    %%=v(@comb3)=%%
```

This is what i've so far! Example of an incoming payload from DE looks like HYU,JUY, ERT

Ultimate goal is to have string look like the following ERT,HYU,JUY.

Comment: If this is for a CloudPage/Code Resource, you should maybe consider using SSJS. It's much more flexible in that you have string.split and can write your own sort function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in all honesty, you could do this via SSJS inside of an email as well. It is actually more performant than a bunch of if statements in a for loop and is simpler to edit/output.

As @Macca said, using split and sort will allow you quite a bit more versatility than what is available in AMPscript. So with using the below, you will be able to sort it in alphabetical order and output as you showed in your example:

```javascript
<script runat=server>

var str = "zd,ae,a,aa,cd,de,ff"
var array = str.split(',');

array.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x < y) { return -1; }
  if (x > y) { return 1; }
  return 0;
});

  Platform.Response.Write('Original String: ' + str);
  
for(i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
  Platform.Response.Write('<br><br>')
  Platform.Response.Write(array[i]);
}
</script>
```

For the sake of keeping processing time low, I made this entirely in Platform library/vanilla JS.  Please do note though that for some reason the default `.sort()` option will not work, you need to define the sort (like I have inside of the above) or it will toss an error `At least one object must implement iComparable`.

Example output:

```
Original String: zd,ae,a,aa,cd,de,ff

a

aa

ae

cd

de

ff

zd
```

If possible, I would try to keep all the needed processing inside of SSJS as mixing languages is not recommended and can affect processing. If you have to use both AMPscript and SSJS, I would make sure to account for a potential slow down - depending on the complexity of your code. To pass AMPscript vars to/from SSJS, check out the [Platform AMPscript Variable Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformAMPscriptVariableFunctions.htm).